# Simplifying multiple similar 'private subs' in VB

Tags: vba

I'm writing a VB program that has multiple positions where when the user hovers over an item, the same image appears.

Currently I have:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(picturePath)
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox2_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.MouseMove
    PictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(picturePath)
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox3_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox3.MouseMove
    PictureBox3.Image = Image.FromFile(picturePath)
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox4_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox4.MouseMove
    PictureBox4.Image = Image.FromFile(picturePath)
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox5_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox5.MouseMove
    PictureBox5.Image = Image.FromFile(picturePath)
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox6_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox6.MouseMove
    PictureBox6.Image = Image.FromFile(picturePath)
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox7_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox7.MouseMove
    PictureBox7.Image = Image.FromFile(picturePath)
End Sub
```

This works fine, however, I am looking to condense my code. Surely there is a way of making this into just 1 or 2 private subs.

Note that this is just a snippet of my code.

The names of the objects are easily named `PictureBox1`, `PictureBox2` etc.

Regards

Hugo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub PictureBox_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove, PictureBox2.MouseMove, PictureBox3.MouseMove, PictureBox4.MouseMove, PictureBox5.MouseMove, PictureBox6.MouseMove, PictureBox7.MouseMove
    DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).Image = Image.FromFile(picturePath)
End Sub
```